# run uniq on csv file ignoring column preserving highest in file

Tags: bash, parsing, csv

A data vendor i use has a bug and are taking a long time to fix it.

Here's a simplified version of the csv files I receive from them:

```
# cat new_data20130904.csv
a,001,b,c,d
e,002,f,g,h
e,003,f,g,h
i,004,j,k,l
```

Column 2 of Rows 2 and 3 are unique, but the data is the same.

Row 3 should never have been created by the vendor, the bug has been 
acknowledged by the vendor and a fix promised, but I don't expect it soon.

I need to parse and modify the CSV file so it becomes:

```
a,001,b,c,d
e,002,f,g,h
i,004,j,k,l
```

I want to code something defensive that will remove these falsely duplicate rows.

Ideally I'd like to use Ubuntu/Debian builtins.

Initially, I thought removing the second field and running through uniq would 
be a good start:

```
# cut -d, -f1,3- new_data20130904.csv | uniq
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
```

But now I can't think of a way of adding column two back in, so I don't think this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ awk -F, '{if (a[$1]) next}a[$1]=$0' file
a,001,b,c,d
e,002,f,g,h
i,004,j,k,l
```

#### Explanation

We store the first column in an array. In case it is already in the array, we skip the record.

- `-F,` sets the field delimiter as comma `,`.
- `{if (a[$1]) next}` in case the first field is already in the array, skip.
- `a[$1]=$0` saves the first field as a key of the array `a` and prints the line (`print $0` is the default behaviour of awk, so it does not need to be written).

> And how would I tweak it if it was the nth column that needed to be
>   ignored?

You can replace `a[$1]` for `a[$n]`, where `n` is the column.

Comment: Awesome, that works on the example I gave, thanks.  Can you explain how it does what it does?  And how wouldIi tweak it if it was the nth column that needed to be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all but one column to be based from when comparing duplicate entries, just delete it on every loop and re-evaluate $0 while saving $0 to another value before it.

```
awk -F, -v i=2 '{t=$0;$i=""}!a[$0]++{print t}' file
```

Where `i` is set to the number of column to ignore.

In `!a[$0]++`, `$0` is already a re-evaluated form where `$i` is already empty, and it stores the key in `a`. If it's not yet stored, the value should be initialy `0` and `!` would cause it to be negated as `1`. `++` would increment it after re-evaluation. If it's initially seen, it would be `0` (negated to `1`) and it would cause the next command to execute which is to print the line. In duplicate entries, it would already be incremented and would negate back to `0` which would not allow the next command to execute.